# Wikia <div> issues

Tags: html, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, wikia

Okay, so I'm working on a template on Wikia, but I'm having a weird issue with my last `<div>` tag that surrounds the Stat Table. Link to the page is [here](http://devilmaker.wikia.com/wiki/Aio_Test) (Note that it can change).

The code is as follows:

```
<div style="background-color: #222; width: 98%; border: .1em solid #4372AA;">
{| border="1" class="article-table" style="margin: 1% auto 1% auto; width:98%;"
! colspan="5" style="text-align:center;"|Level 1
! colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"|Level 40
|-
!
|AP || DP || HP || TP || AP || DP || HP || TP
|-
! [[file:Common.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{CAP1}}} || <small>{{{CDP}}} || <small>{{{CHP1}}} || <small>{{{CTP1}}}
|<small>{{{CAP40}}} || <small>{{{CDP}}} || <small>{{{CHP40}}} || <small>{{{CTP40}}}
|-
![[file:Uncommon.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{UAP1}}} || <small>{{{UDP}}} || <small>{{{UHP1}}} || <small>{{{UTP1}}}
|<small>{{{UAP40}}} || <small>{{{UDP}}} || <small>{{{UHP40}}} || <small>{{{UTP40}}}
|-
![[file:Rare.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{RAP1}}} || <small>{{{RDP}}} || <small>{{{RHP1}}} || <small>{{{RTP1}}}
|<small>{{{RAP40}}} || <small>{{{RDP}}} || <small>{{{RHP40}}} || <small>{{{RTP40}}}
|}
</div>
```

If you visit the page, you'll notice that the closing `</div>` tag displays as text instead of closing off the `div`. (The stat table SHOULD have the same div format as the Fixed Options table. The `div` is essentially copied and pasted for each block, with only the margins edited, but for some reason, it doesn't work around the stat table.)

**EDIT: The link no longer contains the erroneous table. Here is how your table looks like:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your table code, you used one `div` tag, surrounding your wikitable that contains **headers placed after ordinary rows** as well as containing **multiple unclosed** `<small>` **tags**.

`<div style="...">[wikitable]</div>`

Much like HTML, `<div>` specifies a **division** of source code to be styled. In this case, the text of the whole table is to be styled as it is within the only opening and closing `<div>...</div>` bracket.

Delete all `<small>` tags, which removes the trailing `</div>` being displayed, except that the text isn't small anymore. To make them small again, **surround** each text in the table entries with `<small>{{{...}}}</small>`:

```
<div style="background-color: #222; width: 98%; border: .1em solid #4372AA;">
{| border="1" class="article-table" style="margin: 1% auto 1% auto; width:98%;"
! colspan="5" style="text-align:center;"|Level 1
! colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"|Level 40
|-
!
|AP || DP || HP || TP || AP || DP || HP || TP
|-
! [[file:Common.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{CAP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{CDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{CHP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{CTP1}}}</small>
|<small>{{{CAP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{CDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{CHP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{CTP40}}}</small>
|-
![[file:Uncommon.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{UAP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{UDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{UHP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{UTP1}}}</small>
|<small>{{{UAP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{UDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{UHP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{UTP40}}}</small>
|-
![[file:Rare.png|center|]]
|<small>{{{RAP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{RDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{RHP1}}}</small> || <small>{{{RTP1}}}</small>
|<small>{{{RAP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{RDP}}}</small> || <small>{{{RHP40}}}</small> || <small>{{{RTP40}}}</small>
|}
</div>
```

The end result would not have the trailing `</div>` shown, and the entries in `<small>` tags remain smaller than normal-sized text.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any issues. all tables are closed.